# Instagram real-time API POST rate

Tags: instagram

I'm building an application using tag subscriptions in the real-time API and have a question related to capacity planning. We may have a large number of users posting to a subscribed hashtag at once, so the question is how often will the API actually POST to our subscription processing endpoint? E.g., if 100 users post to #testhashtag within a second or two, will I receive 100 POSTs or does the API batch those together as one update? A related question: is there a maximum rate at which POSTs can be sent (e.g., one per second or one per ten seconds, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Instagram API seems to lack detailed information about both how many updates are sent and what are the rate limits. From the [API docs][1]:

> Limits
>   Be nice. If you're sending too many requests too quickly, we'll send back a **503 error code** (server unavailable).
>
> You are limited to **5000 requests per hour** per access_token or client_id overall. Practically, this means you should (when possible) authenticate users so that limits are well outside the reach of a given user.

In other words, you'll need to check for a 503 and throttle your application accordingly. No information I've seen for how long they might block you, but it's best to avoid that completely. I would advise you manage this by placing a rate limiting mechanism on your own code, such as pushing your API requests through a queue with rate control. That will also give you the benefit of a retry of you're throttled so you won't lose any of the updates.

Moreover, a mechanism such as a queue in the case of real-time updates is further relevant because of the following from the API docs:

> You should build your system to accept multiple update objects per payload - though often there will be only one included. Also, you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout--if you need to do more processing of the received information, you can do so in an asynchronous task.

Regarding the number of updates, the API can send you 1 update or many. The problem with this is you can absolutely murder your API calls because I don't think you can batch calls to specific media items, at least not using the official python or ruby clients or API console as far as I have seen.

This means that if you receive 500 updates either as 1 request to your server or split into many, it won't matter because either way, you need to go and fetch these items. From what I observed in a real application, these seemed to count against our quota, however the quota itself seems to consume resources erratically. That is, sometimes we saw no calls at all consumed, other times the available calls dropped by far more than we actually made. My advice is to be conservative and take the 5000 as a best guess rather than an absolute. You can check the remaining calls by parsing one of the headers they send back.

Use common sense, don't be stupid, and using a rate limiting mechanism should keep you safe and have the benefit of dealing with failures either due to outages (this happens more than you may think), network hicups, and accidental rate limiting. You could try to be tricky and use different API keys in a pooling mechanism, but this is likely a violation of the TOS and if they are doing anything via IP, you'd have to split this up to different machines with different IPs.

My final advice would be to restructure your application to not completely rely on the subscription mechanism. It's less than reliable and very expensive API wise. It's only truly useful if you just need to do something in your app that doesn't require calling back to Instgram, your number of items is small, or you can filter out the majority of items to avoid calling back to Instagram accept when a specific business rule is matched.

Instead, you can do things like query the tag or the user (ex: recent media) and scale it out that way. Normally this allows you to grab 100 items with 1 request rather than 100 items with 100 requests. If you really want to be cute, you could at least merge the subscription notifications asynchronously and combine the similar ones into a single batched request when you combine the duplicate characteristics such as tag into a single bucket. Sort of like a map/reduce but on a small data set. You could of course do an actual map/reduce from time-to-time on your own data as another way of keeping things in async. Again, be careful not to thrash instagram, but rather just use map/reduce to batch out your calls in a way that's useful to your app.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is quite helpful. My app is subscribing to tags and all the information we need when taking action on a subscription ping  comes via the `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` endpoint without needing to fetch data in individual photos, so it sounds like the rate limits shouldn't be too much of an obstacle. Adding some mechanism on my end to only hit the tag endpoint at most every 10 seconds regardless of the POST rate should take care of it. The comment on subscriptions being less than reliable is good advice; adding a periodic poll of the tag endpoint should take care of that.

Comment: Sounds good. For anyone else, if it wasn't clear, another option would be to incorporate OAuth and getting permission per user to make requests. This means you can use 5000 requests per each user that authorizes your app to instagram. Of course, this means also you're making calls to the API why you still have a valid OAuth token. If you're just making a server app though, you're stuck with just your own oauth tokens/client id.